Hosting OpenLayers web-map on GitHub Pages?
I am a very much a beginning web-mapper, previously successfully hosting Leaflet maps created with QGIS2web on my GitHub pages. Now I am familiarising myself with OpenLayers web-mapping.
I have successfully created an OpenLayers project, and the web-map looks cool on my localhost address. I would like to host it on GitHub Pages, but have not succeeded with that yet despite of extensive searching of advice.
I created the /dist  directory according to OpenLayers documentation, which contains index.html file, and additional asset files. Opening the index.html file on my browser brings up just blank (and soforth nothing appears on my GitHub Page either). I have also tried with the working files under my-app directory, created by following the OpenLayers instructions. Is it even possible to publish my OL web-map on GitHub pages?
Any tips?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Yes should be possible, check your browser for httprequest errors / CORS. It depends how you import all the external JS/CSS files
